# Como faço para uma palavra ficar junto a borda do container

Tags: css, css3

Preciso que o a palavra (titulo) fique junto a borda do container.
Exemplo abaixo: [Imagem com um layout que preciso fazer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my0JR.png)

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.